# LLVM "/manifestdependency: is not allowed in .drectve" workaround

Tags: compiler-errors, llvm, wxwidgets

I have a relatively complex GUI application built using wxWidgets which I can compile and run fine on MSVC, however when I compile using LLVM in Visual Studio, I have a "/manifestdependency: is not allowed in .drectve" error.

This bug has been reported and a workaround seems to be available here https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38797, however I can't seem to figure out how I need to change my code. In the bug report it mentions how a directive is placed in a PCH file, but I am not using a pre-compiled header in my solution. I can build projects using LLVM where I have not included the wx headers and libraries, so I suspect it is something to do with how wxWidget compiles.

I am not too familiar with how wxWidget works/builds, would anybody be able to give some advice?

Comment: Without [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) there's not much we can do to help you.

Comment: The minimal example given in the wxWidgets windows installer gives the exact same error. https://www.wxwidgets.org/downloads/. Copying the code given in the example isn't much help - it seems to be a linker issue.

Answer (score 1):

With the link mentioned

> https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38797

there was a solution in the [comments](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38797#c3) that worked for me (Adding *case OPT_manifestdependency:* to */lld/COFF/Driver.cpp*).

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/lld/COFF/Driver.cpp b/lld/COFF/Driver.cpp
index 7372505bb61..f8afbb93374 100644
--- a/lld/COFF/Driver.cpp
+++ b/lld/COFF/Driver.cpp
@@ -408,6 +408,7 @@ void LinkerDriver::parseDirectives(InputFile *file) {
     // `#pragma comment(linker, "/flag")`-generated sections.
     case OPT_editandcontinue:
     case OPT_guardsym:
+    case OPT_manifestdependency:
     case OPT_throwingnew:
       break;
     default:
```

It took a while for llvm lld to compile from scratch, but in the end the error message *"error: / manifestdependency: is not allowed in .drectve"* disappeared.

But wxWidgets looked different.
Then I added the file *"wxWidgets/include/wx/msw/amd64_dpi_aware.manifest"* with target_sources in cmake. This fixed the problem with the different look (e.g. blurred font) for me.